# Are the fast integer types faster when stored in the CPU registers?

Tags: c, performance, integer, cpu-registers

I have been thinking about the fast integer types:

`int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t`, `int_fast32_t`, `int_fast64_t`, `uint_fast8_t`, `uint_fast16_t`, `uint_fast32_t`, `uint_fast64_t`

over the last days and I asked a question about *why* (if so) these types are faster than the other integer types:

[Why are the fast integer types faster than the other integer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593541/why-are-the-fast-integer-types-faster-than-the-other-integer-types)

---

Something I have further thought about now is, **if**:

1. Faster types *are* faster on a certain environment (implementation/architecture-dependent) and thus that environment reflects an ideal environment for this question,
2. Objects with the class of `register` *are* stored inside a register of the CPU (but in general do not always need to be stored there when declared with the `register` class), they are faster on the same environment, and
3. A register of the CPU is capable of holding the required integer value,

   ---

   - Are the fast integer types even *faster if declared with the `register` storage class?

Like:

```
register int_fastY_t i;
```

*(*Implying the premises above.*)

Or do they interfere with each other and decrease the performance?

Comment: Do note that `register` is not available in C++.  If you asking about those types of variables then the C++ should be removed.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there something equivalent in C++ for declaring that an object shall be stored in the registers of the CPU?

Comment: Note that the `register` specifier was *deprecated* in C++11 and *removed* in C++17. *Don't* use it.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Nope.  C++ has `static`, `thread_local`, `extern`, and `mutable`

Comment: @NathanOliver Untagged C++.

Comment: "Is there something equivalent in C++ for declaring that an object shall be stored in the registers of the CPU?" - No. You should leave register allocation to your compiler. It'll do a better job than you ever could (most likely), in any case.

Comment: C 2018 6.7.1 6 says “A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier `register` suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.” That is all it is, a suggestion. It does not require the implementation to store the value in a register, and its usefulness with good modern compilers is limited—they already optimize well.

Comment: What about x86_64 and the REX prefix bytes?

Answer (score 4):

Everything is faster when stored in CPU registers.

`register` does not cause the compiler to store a value in a register. `register` does absolutely nothing. Only extremely old compilers used `register` to know which variables to store in registers. New compilers do it automatically. Even 20-year-old compilers do it automatically.

It sounds like you are trying to make a program faster but you don't understand what the program is actually doing, so you are asking about all the speed-related things that you have ever heard about.

I remind you that if you're on x86-64 using GCC, for example, then `int_fast16_t` is the same as `int64_t`, which is the same as `int` and `register` does absolutely nothing, so `register int_fast16_t` is the same as `int`. It's not a magic speed-up command.

If you want to use these kinds of tricks to make your program faster, you should start by reading the assembly code that your compiler produces. [Information for GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc) or [Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c). Then you can look for inefficient assembly code, and when you find some, you can find out how to speed it up. Right now, you are [tilting at windmills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quixote#Tilting_at_windmills).

Comment: Newer compilers do take `register` into consideration`.

Comment: Even in old compilers, register` was a hint to the optimizer, much as `volatile` is.

Comment: Why is `int64_t` faster than 32-bit accesses? Slicing shouldn't take extra machine cycles or uops and 32-bit operands are shorter by a byte, reducing pressure on the I-cache and instruction fetch.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ-- I think accessing 32-bit values requires an extra instruction byte.

Comment: @user253751 No, instruction encoding defaults to a 32-bit register. To access the full 64 bits, the `REX` prefix is required. `inc eax;` takes two bytes: `ff c0`, while `inc rax` takes three: `48 ff c0`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the answer here is a consultant's favorite: "it depends". Using a new keyword won't make the underlying CPU any faster — that's a hint to the compiler to use the fastest type. In many architectures, keeping numbers in registers does make arithmetic faster, but that doesn't mean it will be faster in any architecture, and in any case, the `register` keyword is another hint to the compiler — it doesn't guarantee any constraints on the generated code, especially after optimization.