# Shall I use register class variables in modern C programs?

Tags: c, cpu-registers, storage-class-specifier

In C++, the keyword `register` was removed in its latest standard ISO/IEC 14882:2017 (C++17).

But also in C, I see a lot, that more and more coders tend to not use or like to declare an object with the `register` class qualifier because its purposed benefit shall be almost useless, like in [@user253751´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59616089/12139179):

> `register` does not cause the compiler to store a value in a register. `register` does absolutely nothing. Only extremely old compilers used `register` to know which variables to store in registers. New compilers do it automatically. Even 20-year-old compilers do it automatically.

- Is the use of `register` class variables and with that the use of the keyword `register` deprecated?
- Shall I use `register` class variables in my modern programs? Or is this behavior  redundant and deprecated?

Comment: If it's deprecated, you probably don't want to use it :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: It's deprecated or removed in C++, but I don't think it is in C.

Answer (score 5):

There is no benefit to using `register`.  Modern compilers substantially ignore it — they can handle register allocation better than you can.  The only thing it prevents is taking the address of the variable, which is not a significant benefit.

None of my own code uses `register` any more.  The code I work on loses `register` when I get to work on a file — but it takes time to get through 17,000+ files (and I only change a file when I have an external reason to change it — but it can be a flimsy reason).

Answer (score 3):

As @JonathanLeffler stated it is ignored in most cases.

Some compilers have a special extension syntax if you want to keep the variable in the particular register.

*gcc* Global or local variable can be placed in the particular register. This option is not available for all platforms. I know that AVR & ARM ports implement it.

example:

```
register int x asm ("10");

int foo(int y)
{
    x = bar(x);
    x = bar1(x);
    return x*x;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qwAZ8x

More information: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html#Explicit-Register-Variables

But to be honest I was never using it in my programming life (30y+)

Answer (score 1):

It's effectively deprecated and offers no real benefit.

C is a product of the early 1970s, and the `register` keyword served as a hint to the compiler that a) this particular object was going to be used a lot, so b) you might want to store it somewhere other than main memory - IOW, a register or some other "fast" memory.

It *may* have made a difference then - now, it's pretty much ignored.  The only measurable effect is that it prevents you from taking the address of that object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this feature is NOT deprecated because: "register" in this context (global or local register variables) is a GNU extension which are not deprecated.

In your example, R10 (or the register that GCC internally assigns REGNO(reg) = 10), is a global register.  "global" here means, that *all* code in your application must agree on that usage.  This is usually not the case for code from libraries like libc, libm or libgcc because they are not compiled with -ffixed-10.  Moreover, global registers might conflict with the ABI.  avr-gcc for example might pass values in R10.  In avr-gcc, R2...R9 are not used by the ABI and not by code from libgcc (except for 64-bit double).

In some hard real-time app with avr-gcc I used global regs in a (premature) optimization, just to notice that the performance gain was miniscule.

Local register variables, however, are very handy when it comes to integrating non-ABI functions for example assembly functions that don't comply to the GCC ABI, without the need for assembly wrappers.